The shape of water drop on smooth solid surface
We know that the shape of a water drop satisfies the Young-Laplace equation: $\Delta p = 2\gamma H$, where $\Delta p$ is the pressure difference between the inside and outside surface of the water drop, and $H$ is the mean curvature. Assuming the water drop is on a smooth solid surface, at the boundary of water drop it satisfies $\frac{\partial u}{\partial {\vec{n}}} = \tan \theta_C$, where $\theta_C$ is the contact angle (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_angle), and $\vec{n}$ is the normal vector at the boundary.
Let the water drop occupy an open set $\Omega$, and the height at point $(x, y)$ be denoted by $u(x,y)$. Define $\Gamma := \partial \Omega$. We have
$$ -\gamma \nabla \cdot \left(\frac{\nabla u}{\sqrt{1 + |\nabla u|^2}}\right) = p_1 - p_0 - \rho g u, \quad \text{ in } \Omega, $$
where $p_1$ is the pressure inside the water drop at height 0 (near the solid surface), $p_0$ is the atmospheric pressure. However, there are two boundary conditions at $\Gamma$: $u |_\Gamma = 0, \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{\vec{n}}} \bigg|_\Gamma = \tan \theta_C$. Typically, a second-order (nonlinear) elliptic equation has either a Dirichlet boundary condition or a Newmann boundary condition. Having both can result in an overdetermined system, which may not have a solution.
Thus, I'm asking for a condition on $\Gamma$ that allows the system to admit a solution. Trivially, assuming $u$ is rotationally symmetric, we can set $u(x, y) = f(r)$, where $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$, and find a solution that satisfies both conditions. While this solution resembles an ellipsoid, it is not exactly one. It this the unique solution that satisfies both boundary conditions?
